# CKEditor, Roxy Fileman, Add File -upload fails in Firefox

Tags: firefox, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor with Roxy File Manager -plugin. In the file manager dialog window, when I use the Add File -button to upload a file into server, it works fine in IE11 and Chrome. Firefox though fails to upload the file.

I have been debugging the source of Fileman and I guess the problem is in main.js (I'm using minimized version main.min.js). In function addFile() in the next code part:

```
if(!RoxyFilemanConf.UPLOAD){
    alert(t("E_ActionDisabled"))
}
else{
    console.log(document.forms.addfile);
    document.forms.addfile.action=RoxyFilemanConf.UPLOAD;
    console.log(document.forms.addfile);
    document.forms.addfile.submit();
}
```

I have added my debugging (console.log). It seems that Firefox fails to add action for the addfile form, since the debug gives same content before and after the adding:

```
<form id="frmUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="frmUploadFile" method="post" name="addfile">
```

Have anyone else encountered this problem, or does anyone know if there's something different in handling this kind of code in Firefox?

Any suggestions how to find the reason for this not working in Firefox?

Filemans upload.php is not loaded at all, since action is not added for the form.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this issue and fixed it with this:-

```
 $('form[name="addfile"]').attr('action', RoxyFilemanConf.UPLOAD);
```

instead of

```
 document.forms.addfile.action=RoxyFilemanConf.UPLOAD;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thx. it also helped me. (try upload png still failed. but upload jpg fine) hahaha

Answer (score 0):

The solution from BG101 is working fine.
i'm also stuck in uploading png files. with the defaults setting of ckeditor+roxyfileman.
maybe u(user2122600) also stuck like me ? do u already try to upload jpg files? it works with me.

hope this helps too.